# Override/Extend type defined in another file

Tags: typescript

**Problem:**
I'm trying to extend a type used by a function to be able to test it with stub values.

`foo.ts` exports a function `foo(input: FooInput)`, where `FooInput` is defined in the same file.

```js
// foo.ts
export enum FooInput {
  bar,
  buzz,
}
export default function foo(input: FooInput) {}
```

To test `foo`, I don't want to extend `FooInput` with a test-only value to decouple the tests from the `FooInput`'s current definition.

```
// foo.test.ts
import foo, {FooInput} from './foo.ts';

FooInput.test = 'test' // Extend FooInput with 'test' key invalid

// declare ... (?)

// Test foo by calling foo(FooInput.test) <- The dream
```

I'm not that experience with using `declare`, but I feel like the solution might involve it somehow to override `FooInput`.

I don't need the original `FooInput` keys, it could just have the stub keys.